# Opacity transitioning not working correctly in Tailwindcss suddenly

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a parent div with two children where when you hover over it, it sets a state and also changes opacity so one div with a number number fades and a React Icon appears in its place. This was working last night, yet for some reason when I open VSCode today it's refusing to work anymore.

Here's the code:

```
                            <div className={`group w-full flex justify-between box-border items-center rounded-lg hover:bg-[#4c426e] cursor-pointer self-stretch min-w-0 h-[50px] p-0 mb-2 relative`} 
                                onMouseEnter={() => setHovered(true)}
                                onMouseLeave={() => setHovered(false)}>
                                <div className={`w-full text-[12px] min-w-[35px] max-w-[35px] text-left ml-2 self-center shrink text-lg text-[#989898] relative`}>
                                    <div className={`absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full flex items-center justify-center transition-all ease-in-out duration-300`}>
                                        <span className={`absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full flex items-center justify-center opacity-${hovered ? '0' : '100'} transition-all ease-in-out duration-300`} >
                                            {number}
                                        </span>
                                        {hovered && <span className={`absolute bottom-0 left-0 w-full h-full flex items-center justify-center opacity-${hovered ? '100' : '0'} transition-all ease-in-out duration-300`} >
                                            <FaPlay onClick={() => handlePlay(title, artist)}/>
                                        </span>}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Can anyone identify something that's wrong here, or is mt Tailwind install just being weird suddenly?

Comment: I've gotten it working again with this:

style={{ opacity: hovered ? 0 : 100 }}

Just deleting the opacity code and put that in its place and the reverse numbers for the other. Out of all the issues I've had so far this puzzles me the most though; it was working perfectly fine last night, somehow coming back to it it doesn't?
Guess that's programming for you!

Answer (score 4):

You should always use the full name of Tailwind classes, otherwise they will no be included in the build. Tailwind optimizes the CSS output by only including classes that you use.

You should rather be doing it like this:

```
hovered ? 'opacity-0' : 'opacity-100'
```

Read more here:
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production

Comment: That partially worked, though only for the number. The icon seems to still just show instantly. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: Might be because you are also hiding it with javascript so it never goes from 0 opacity to 100. It only renders when it's already set to 100